# Swift TabBar Item color and background color

Tags: swift, ios8, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to set the icon color and background color of an individual item on my TabBar within the TabBarController.

I have 5 icons on my TabBar, 4 of which i've set the color for, it's just this last icon that i'm struggling with. I've attached a link below of an image to show what i'm trying to achieve.

The specific icon is (the one in the middle of the image) for my camera feed, this icon i would like to be white and the background to be red.
My code so far is such -
On my TabBarController:

```
var imageNames = ["FeedIcon", "ExploreIcon", "CameraIcon", "ActivityIcon", "MyProfileIcon"]

    let tabItems = tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem]
    for (index, value) in enumerate(tabItems)
    {
       var imageName = imageNames[index]
        value.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        value.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 0, -5.0, 0)

    }
    //for below i've used a extension for imageWithColor to set the color of my icons
    for tabItems in self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem] {
        if let image = tabItems.image {
            tabItems.image = image.imageWithColor(UIColor(red: 57.0/255.0, green: 57.0/255.0, blue: 57.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        }
    }
```

My Extension:

```
    extension UIImage {
    func imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() as CGContextRef
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal)

        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) as CGRect
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)
        tintColor.setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as UIImage
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late but to create this "camera item" I think the only solution is to create a UIButton and set the center of the button to the center of the UITabBar. You can see how to do it in this [post](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/). After that you can set the image to the button with this background color.

**UPDATE:**

I created this [sample project](https://github.com/angeldev/iOSDev/tree/master/buttonOnTabBar) written with swift where you can see how to add this button on the tabBar.

The main issue is to subclass UITabBarController and add the button from this class.

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        // Creates image of the Button
        let imageCameraButton: UIImage! = UIImage(named: "cameraIcon")

        // Creates a Button
        let cameraButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        // Sets width and height to the Button
        cameraButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageCameraButton.size.width, imageCameraButton.size.height);
        // Sets image to the Button
        cameraButton.setBackgroundImage(imageCameraButton, forState: .Normal)
        // Sets the center of the Button to the center of the TabBar
        cameraButton.center = self.tabBar.center
        // Sets an action to the Button
        cameraButton.addTarget(self, action: "doSomething", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        // Adds the Button to the view
        self.view.addSubview(cameraButton)

    }

    func doSomething() {

        print("Action of camera button")

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @angeldev, i'll have a look at this and let you know if it resolves the problem.

Comment: @ggomersall I have just try it in one of my projects and it works for me. I did it with swift as well. If you have any problem, just let me know :).

Comment: awesome!! I'll let you know